# How make a simpler expresion for showing multiple RecyclerView in one Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to make multiple RecyclerView divided by TextView in each RecyclerView, this code works for me but I want to make the code simpler. Could someone help me with this?

Here is my Activity.java:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle("Tuntunan Toharoh");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    //=============================================================
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    RecyclerView.Adapter tadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mRecyclerViewItems);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(tadapter);
    addMenuItemsFromJson();
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    //=========================================================
    DzRecyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_submenu);
    DzRecyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager zlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    DzRecyclerView2.setLayoutManager(zlayoutManager);

    RecyclerView.Adapter zadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mRecyclerViewItems2);
    DzRecyclerView2.setAdapter(zadapter);
    addMenuItemsFromJson2();
    DzRecyclerView2.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    //=========================================================
    DzaRecyclerView3 = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_mandi);
    DzaRecyclerView3.setHasFixedSize(true);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager zzlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    DzaRecyclerView3.setLayoutManager(zzlayoutManager);

    RecyclerView.Adapter ziadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), mRecyclerViewItems3);
    DzaRecyclerView3.setAdapter(ziadapter);
    addMenuItemsFromJson3();
    DzaRecyclerView3.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    //=========================================================

    return view;


private void addMenuItemsFromJson() {
    try {
        String jsonDataString = readJsonDataFromFile();
        JSONArray menuItemsJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

        for (int i = 0; i < menuItemsJsonArray.length(); ++i) {

            JSONObject menuItemObject = menuItemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String menuItemtitle = menuItemObject.getString("title");
            String menuItemContent = menuItemObject.getString("content");

            DafAdapter dafa = new DafAdapter(menuItemtitle, menuItemContent);
            mRecyclerViewItems.add(dafa);
        }
    } catch (IOException | JSONException exception) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Unable to parse JSON file.", exception);
    }
}


private String readJsonDataFromFile() throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        String jsonDataString = null;
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tayamum);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        while ((jsonDataString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(jsonDataString);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    return new String(builder);
}

private void addMenuItemsFromJson2() {
    try {
        String jsonDataString = readJsonDataFromFile2();
        JSONArray menuItemsJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

        for (int i = 0; i < menuItemsJsonArray.length(); ++i) {

            JSONObject menuItemObject = menuItemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String menuItemtitle = menuItemObject.getString("title");
            String menuItemContent = menuItemObject.getString("content");

            DafAdapter dafa = new DafAdapter(menuItemtitle, menuItemContent);
            mRecyclerViewItems2.add(dafa);
        }
    } catch (IOException | JSONException exception) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Unable to parse JSON file.", exception);
    }
}

private String readJsonDataFromFile2() throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        String jsonDataString = null;
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wudhu);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        while ((jsonDataString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(jsonDataString);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    return new String(builder);
}
private void addMenuItemsFromJson3() {
    try {
        String jsonDataString = readJsonDataFromFile3();
        JSONArray menuItemsJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);

        for (int i = 0; i < menuItemsJsonArray.length(); ++i) {

            JSONObject menuItemObject = menuItemsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String menuItemtitle = menuItemObject.getString("title");
            String menuItemContent = menuItemObject.getString("content");

            DafAdapter dafa = new DafAdapter(menuItemtitle, menuItemContent);
            mRecyclerViewItems3.add(dafa);
        }
    } catch (IOException | JSONException exception) {
        Log.e(MainActivity.class.getName(), "Unable to parse JSON file.", exception);
    }
}

private String readJsonDataFromFile3() throws IOException {

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        String jsonDataString = null;
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mandi);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        while ((jsonDataString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(jsonDataString);
        }
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }

    return new String(builder);
}
```

If i want to add one or more RecyclerView, it just makes a similar expression just change expression 1 to others. I think it can be simpler than that code.

I have tried a switch and an if block, but I haven't had any luck. How would I do that?

Comment: Can you attach your design what you wanna do exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not put the list of RecyclerViews and TextViews in a vertical Recyclerview

so you can bind them dynamically

**EDIT**

in order to create a vertical recycler view, you should first see if it possible to wrap all you row data in a single `List` or not?

thus if that is possible only thing remaining is to create a vertical `LayoutManager` to show your rows. something like : `new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)`
and assign it to your new `RecyclerView` from there on only thing remaining is creating `ViewHolders` and binding them with the data. which is very simple.

you can check this [sample project](https://github.com/msahakyan/nested-recycler-view) out for better understanding

Comment: i don't know how to create vertical Recyclerview